# iPad Popup Form

Tags: xcode, forms, popup

I have iPad application with main view controller with a navigation bar at the top. I want to create a signIn button on navigation bar, which should open a popupview with username, password, one additional field and a login button. Clicking login button will close the popover and pass the information from text field back to main view controller.

I have been trying to find something like this on web , but no luck.

Does anyone knows a way to do this ?

Comment: What part exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [UIPopoverController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

This is how you initialize and show it:

```
UIPopoverController *myPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myForm];
[myPopover presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionsAny animated:YES];
```

To get data back from `myForm` you probably want to use [delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c/).

```
myForm.delegate = self; //before presenting de popover
```